# android layout header gravity small issue

Tags: android, layout

I have layout header with two items. With TextView and Button. But i cant make them stay in right alignments. im trying to use android:gravity="..." and layout_gravity="..." inside elements, but it just dont take any effect.

Only if i apply extra LinearLayout like in this code, i can make them center. But still i cant make TextView be "center" and Button "right".

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical"    
android:id="@+id/customLayout"
android:background="#708090"
>

    <LinearLayout  android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:textSize="40px"
    android:text="Yolo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mapButton"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/map"
    android:gravity="right"
     />

     </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout. 
For TextView, set both "android:gravity" and "android:layout_gravity" to be "center". 
For the ImageView, simply set its "android:layout_alignParentRight" to be "true".